# Is this the preferred way to convert a char to a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, character

While writing unit tests for a function returning `boolean` that takes two `String`s, and I needed to test every character of the alphabet (`'a'`-`'z'`) in sequence as one of the parameters, one-by-one, so I wrote this to do that:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    assertTrue(MyClass.MyFunction(testSubject, new String(c));
}
```

I would have thought this was permissible, but it wasn't, so I just did it like this instead:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
{
    assertTrue(MyClass.MyFunction(testSubject, ((Character) c).toString());
}
```

Is this a reliable method to convert a `char` to a `String` in Java? Is it the preferred way? I don't know a whole lot about Java so would like some clarification on this.

Comment: Not directly to your question, but I would `IntStream.range(0, 26).mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) ('a' + i))).forEach(x -> assertTrue(MyClass.MyFunction(testSubject, x)));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but why? Streams are unnecessary here, but even if you insist on using streams for every loop, why not at least use `IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z')`?

Comment: There is no single 'correct' way. There are probably at least five ways to do this: which you choose depends on fashion as much as scientific fact. Most of the time it simply doesn't matter, and a test program is certainly one of those cases.

Comment: @PhilipRoman Because it is there (Edmund Hillary). Because I can. Because we want to (Billie Piper, I think). That's a cool approach too.

Comment: _I would have thought this was permissible_ You thought it was permissible to invoke a `String` constructor that doesn't exist? Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I am aware, there is not constructor in class [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) that takes a single `char` argument. Note that `char` is not the same as `char[]`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The shortest solution:

```
char c = 'a';
String s = "" + c;
```

The cleanest (and probably most efficient<sup>1</sup>) solutions:

```
char c = 'a';

String s1 = String.valueOf(c);
// or
String s2 = Character.toString(c);
```

Compared to your approach, the above prevents the overhead of having to box the primitive into a `Character` object.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The slight inefficiency of the string concatenation in the first approach might be optimized away by the compiler or runtime, so one (if one were so inclined) would really have to run a micro-benchmark to determine actual performance. Micro-optimizations like this are rarely worth the effort, and relying on concatenation to force string conversion just doesn't look very nice.</sup>

Comment: Last time I looked, Sun's `javac` compiler automatically transforms `String s = "" + c;` into `String s = String.valueOf(c);`, so the performance would be the same.

Comment: @Neil Whew! I was beginning to think that the type of person I wrote that footnote for no longer existed on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @Neil: Weird! For me both javac 1.8.0_101 and Eclipse compiler emits code for creating the `StringBuilder` and calling `append`. Javac 10.0.1 emits an invoke-dynamic instruction. Maybe they trusted the JIT more in later years, instead of making compile time optimizations.